# How to add padding on the git bash window

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows

[image]

Is there a way to add padding to the git bash window?

trying to achieve this:
[image]

Comment: You might want to clarify what exactly you mean by padding. Is it extra space around each command? Extra space around each line? Extra space around each character? etc.

Comment: Updated sir....

Comment: @Stackchampu So my answer stands: yes, provided you are using the right CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add padding to the git bash window?

No: not in a regular Git bash window itself.

If you are using the [Windows 10/11 terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), then yes, with the [padding setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-appearance#padding):

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/images/padding.gif]

From there, you can type '`bash`', and enter a [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) bash session.

This comes from [issue 76](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/76), which illustrates one aspect of padding, assuming this is what the OP was referring to:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25664275/31866497-84d1b6cc-b780-11e7-962c-165d02c9bf20.png]

Comment: I didn't completely understand your answer. padding not possible in Gitbash?

Comment: @Stackchampu No it is not. It is only possible in a Windows CLI named "terminal". Then, in that CLI, you can launch a Git bash session, by typing bash.

Comment: Thanks sir, for the clarification.